# Cannot add a new role to any case

Tags: civicase

In a Case, when I try to add a New Role, there is an Error warning.
First I get the window to indicate *Relationship Type* and to *Assign To:*, then no role is added.

*Error
API (EntitySetting, get) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)*

Here's the ConfigAndLog :

Thanks for help in the matter.

```
   $Fatal Error Details = array(3) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(77) "API (EntitySetting, get) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)"
  ["code"]=>
  NULL
  ["exception"]=>
  object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception)#608 (8) {
    ["extraParams":"CiviCRM_API3_Exception":private]=>
    array(3) {
      ["is_error"]=>
      int(1)
      ["error_message"]=>
      string(77) "API (EntitySetting, get) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)"
      ["error_code"]=>
      string(9) "undefined"
    }
    ["message":protected]=>
    string(77) "API (EntitySetting, get) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)"
    ["string":"Exception":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["code":protected]=>
    int(0)
    ["file":protected]=>
    string(71) "/var/data/sites/photo/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php"
    ["line":protected]=>
    int(45)
    ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
    array(10) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(81) "/var/data/sites/photo/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(3122)
        ["function"]=>
        string(12) "civicrm_api3"
        ["args"]=>
                string(12) "civicrm_api3"
        ["args"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(12) "relationship"
          [1]=>
          string(6) "create"
          [2]=>
          array(3) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(4) "5467"
            ["is_active"]=>
            int(0)
            ["end_date"]=>
            string(3) "now"
          }
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(85) "/var/data/sites/photo/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/AJAX.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(242)
        ["function"]=>
        string(11) "endCaseRole"
        ["class"]=>
        string(17) "CRM_Case_BAO_Case"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(4) {
          [0]=>
          string(1) "1"
          [1]=>
          string(1) "b"
          [2]=>
          string(1) "2"
          [3]=>
          string(1) "9"
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["function"]=>
        string(12) "relationship"
        ["class"]=>
        string(21) "CRM_Contact_Page_AJAX"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
               ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      array(4) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(79) "/var/data/sites/photo/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(275)
        ["function"]=>
        string(14) "call_user_func"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(21) "CRM_Contact_Page_AJAX"
            [1]=>
            string(12) "relationship"
          }
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(79) "/var/data/sites/photo/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(84)
        ["function"]=>
        string(7) "runItem"
        ["class"]=>
        string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(12) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(3) "215"
            ["domain_id"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["path"]=>
            string(21) "civicrm/ajax/relation"
            ["access_callback"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              string(19) "CRM_Core_Permission"
              [1]=>
              string(9) "checkMenu"
            }

                         string(9) "checkMenu"
            }
            ["access_arguments"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(14) "access CiviCRM"
              }
              [1]=>
              string(3) "and"
            }
            ["page_callback"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              string(21) "CRM_Contact_Page_AJAX"
              [1]=>
              string(12) "relationship"
            }
            ["breadcrumb"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              array(2) {
                ["title"]=>
                string(7) "CiviCRM"
                ["url"]=>
                string(16) "/civicrm?reset=1"
              }
            }
            ["is_ssl"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["weight"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["type"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["page_type"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["page_arguments"]=>
            bool(false)
          }
        }
      }
      [5]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(79) "/var/data/sites/photo/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(52)
        ["function"]=>
        string(7) "_invoke"
        ["class"]=>
        string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke"
        ["class"]=>
        string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(7) "civicrm"
            [1]=>
            string(4) "ajax"
            [2]=>
            string(8) "relation"
          }
        }
      }
      [6]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(81) "/var/data/sites/photo/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module"
        ["line"]=>
        int(448)
        ["function"]=>
        string(6) "invoke"
        ["class"]=>
        string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          &array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(7) "civicrm"
            [1]=>
            string(4) "ajax"
            [2]=>
            string(8) "relation"
          }
        }
      }
      [7]=>
      array(2) {
        ["function"]=>
        string(14) "civicrm_invoke"
        ["args"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          &string(4) "ajax"
          [1]=>
          &string(8) "relation"
         [1]=>
          &string(8) "relation"
        }
      }
      [8]=>
      array(4) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(51) "/var/data/sites/photo/public_html/includes/menu.inc"
        ["line"]=>
        int(527)
        ["function"]=>
        string(20) "call_user_func_array"
        ["args"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          &string(14) "civicrm_invoke"
          [1]=>
          &array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(4) "ajax"
            [1]=>
            string(8) "relation"
          }
        }
      }
      [9]=>
      array(4) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(43) "/var/data/sites/photo/public_html/index.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(21)
        ["function"]=>
        string(27) "menu_execute_active_handler"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
    ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
    NULL
  }
}


Nov 26 13:11:45  [info] $backTrace = #0 /var/data/sites/photo/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(456): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace",$
#1 /var/data/sites/photo/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(55): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception))
#2 /var/data/sites/photo/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "relation")
#4 /var/data/sites/photo/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#5 /var/data/sites/photo/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#6 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem was not from the code**. But that was in fact from imported data in the table *civicrm_relationship*. There were in the table some data left by a test (in the case_id column). My mistake.
So the matter is solved.